# Strange Behaviour With Title Bar Color

Tags: android

I intent to change the title bar color and actually it works pretty well.

```
<style name="CustomTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    [...]
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/TitlebarBackground.Dark</item>
</style>

<style name="TitlebarBackground.Dark">
    <item name="android:background">#303031</item>
</style>
```

I have a `PreferenceActivity`. I apply a background drawable to the `ListView` for having a border with rounded corners. And now I want to equalize the title bar color with the border color, so in this case I want the title bar color to be `#303030`. But as soon as the title bar color has exactly the same as the border color, it becomes clean black `#000000`:

[image]

When I set the title bar color to **almost** the same as the border color - for example `#303031` - everything works fine:

[image]

Here's the background drawable which generates the border with rounded corners:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/border_color" />

    <solid android:color="@color/bg_color" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Does anybody have **any** explanation for this... well... strange behaviour?

**edit:**
What - for some strange reason - works as well is setting the title bar background color programmatically:

```
View title = ((ListActivity) context).getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
titleBar.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.border_color_dark));
```

That way I can equalize both colors as well. Still, I don't understand why specifying the title bar color in `XML` does not work. No clue. Very mysterious.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the [CacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#cacheColorHint) attribute, but i am not sure... it definitely looks like some android optimization.